# Ubuntu 20.04 and SDR - using RSP1A with CLI

Tags: command-line

I want use RSP1A - SDR Receiver on Ubuntu 20.04. My purpose is a using a command line program to save in file data for instance in this format

```
Date Stamp, VFO Freq (Hz), Power (dBm), SNR (dB)
14:19:35, 107500000, -82.9, 32.8
```

First i think about CubicSDR ( to check RSP1A work ) and install them. Program is very nice - i can check every radio station and saw charts of frequency but i cannot find option "save output to csv/file" and command line options. Do you recommended any CLI programs ?

EDIT: ok, cubisdr don't have option to save data SNR and PWR
https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicSDR/issues/905

Maybe you have idea about other program at Linux who can do this?

Comment: The official site https://www.sdrplay.com/downloads/ lists SoapySDR at https://www.sdrplay.com/dload/dl3a.php . Have you tried it?